# NHibernate QueryOver sum the values of a field in a collection

Tags: .net, nhibernate, queryover

I have a parent object containing a collection of children:

```
class Parent {  
    int Id {get;set;}
    ....
    IList<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

 class Child {
    int Id {get;set;}
    int Value {get;set;}
    ...
    Parent Parent {get;set;}
 }
```

The mapping whith FluentNHibernate is

ParentMap:

```
Id(x => x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
...
HasMany<Child>(x => x.Children).AsBag().KeyColumn("parentid").Inverse()
    .Fetch.Join().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

ChildMap:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
....
Map(x => x.Value, "value");
References<Parent>(x => x.Parent, "parentid").NotFound.Ignore();
```

I have to map whith NHibernate a SQL query like this:

```
select p.id, sum(c.value)
from parent p, child c
where p.id = c.parentid
```

Is it possible to translate this query whith QueryOver?

Thanks

Comment: see the example for using 'average' under the 'projections' section here. you can do the same for 'sum'. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx

Comment: Jhonny, thanks for your reply. My problem is different from the case explained in that example. I want to get the sum of "Value" properties; I would something like this:
IList selection =
    session.QueryOver<Parent>()
        .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Property<Parent>(c => c.Id))
            .Add(Projections.Sum<Child>(c => c.Value)))
        .List<object[]>();
But this is not possible, because I'm not able to get the sum of the Value of the joined Children

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
Child childAlias = null;
var selection = session.QueryOver<Parent>()
    .JoinAlias(p => p.Childs, () => childAlias)
    .Select(Projections.Group(Projections.Id()), Projections.Sum(() => childAlias.Value))
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(arr => new { Id = (int)arr[0], Sum = (int)arr[1] });
```

or this

```
Child parentAlias = null;
var selection = session.QueryOver(() => parentAlias)
    .Select(Projections.Id(), Projections.SubQuery(QueryOver.Of<Child>()
        .Where(c => c.Parent == parentAlias)
        .Select(Projections.Sum<Child>(c => c.Value))
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(arr => new { Id = (int)arr[0], Sum = (int)arr[1] });
```

or this

```
IList selection = from p in session.Query<Parent>
                  select new { p.Id, Sum = p.Childs.Sum(c => c.Value) };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: the first solution is what I'm looking for. I have added the grouping clause, so the solution is:
    Child childAlias = null;
    var selection = session.QueryOver<Parent>()
        .JoinAlias(p => p.Children, () => childAlias)
        .Select(Projections.Id(), Projections.Sum(() => childAlias.Value), Projections.Group<Parent>(p => p.Id))
       .List<object[]>()
       .Select(arr => new { Id = (int)arr[0], Sum = (int)arr[1] });

Comment: i will add it to the answer. the second query should work too, no?